# ValueError: `class_weight` must contain all classes in the data. The classes {1, 2, 3} exist in the data but not in `class_weight`

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

> ValueError: `class_weight` must contain all classes in the data. The classes {1, 2, 3} exist in the data but not in `class_weight`

I am trying to assign class-weights to my un-balanced classes but after model.fit() it generates this error although i seen other solutions already given for this problem but still unable to solve it.

```
test_split=round(n*2/3)
x_train=x[:test_split]
y_train=y[:test_split]
x_test=x[test_split:]
y_test=y[test_split:]

class_weight_list = compute_class_weight('balanced', numpy.unique(y_train), y_train)
class_weight = dict(zip(numpy.unique(y_train), class_weight_list))
x_train=x_train.astype('float64')
x_test=x_test.astype('float64')

x_train/=255
x_test/=255

y_train=keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test=keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
hist=model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
               batch_size=batch_size,
               epochs=epochs,
               validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
               callbacks=[checkpoint],
               class_weight=class_weight
               )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try label encoding first

EDIT

```
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y_train)
y_train= encoder.transform(y_train)
y_test= encoder.transform(y_test)

class_weight_list = compute_class_weight('balanced', numpy.unique(y_train), y_train)
class_weight = dict(zip(numpy.unique(y_train), class_weight_list))

y_train=keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
```

Comment: It throws error **unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'**

Comment: **ValueError: bad input shape (11750, 4)**

Comment: can you print head of your original y_train input?

Comment: this (11750, 100, 100, 1)
(11750,)
(5875, 100, 100, 1)
(5875,) #x=x.reshape((-1,100,100,1)) # i reshaped to 4